# Finding workings days for a month

Tags: 2013, calculated-column

I have a SharePoint list having field as `WorkingDays` like workday1, 2, 3 etc.

For each and every column I have different reports. I need to create a calculated column for all working days for a month.

Below is the sample format.

```
Field1  Field2  Field3  Field4  Field5   Field6(has to find) 
Report1 Daily   No      Daily   Daily   
Report2 Daily   Yes     Weekly  Tuesday 
Report3 Daily   No      Monthly Workday2    
Report4 Weekly  No      Monthly Workday3     
Report5 Weekly  No      Monthly Workday8    
Report6 Daily   No      Monthly Third Thursday  
Report7 Daily   Yes     Daily   3 Hours before EOD  
Report8 Daily   No      Monthly Next Wednesday of first Thursday    
Report9 Monthly No      Monthly Monday before last Thursday of the month
```

Here `field6` is the duedate I need to find, based on field5.

Can anyone please help me how to create formula for these? Other than calculated field what can we do?

Comment: what is the formulae you want to implement to calculate the value?

Comment: List the values you expect to see in Field6

Comment: Field6
1-Jun-17
6-Jun-17
2-Jun-17
5-Jun-17
12-Jun-17
15-Jun-17

7-Jun-17
26-Jun-17